# Is ( Set S contains $x$ and only $x$ then does S equals $x$ ) true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, philosophy

If a set $S$ contains $x$ and only $x$, then does $S$ equal $x$?

Comment: No, because one is a set and the other is an element

Comment: @Surb Sets can also be elements of sets. I think in set theory everything is a set (or there are strict classes also). But set can't be its own element.

Comment: @ploosu2 you are right, but to the best of my knowledge if $x \in E$ and $S=\{x\}$ then $S\in\mathcal{P}(E)\neq E$, where $\mathcal{P}(E)$ is the set of all subsets of $E$.

Comment: In particular most set theories have axioms that forbid $x=\{x\}$.  See the [Axiom of Regularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity), sometimes called the Axiom of Foundation.

Comment: @hardmath If you make an answer with this, I'd be happy to +1 it.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that axiom of foundation is independent from other axioms, so there's really nothing preventing that $x\in x$, or $x=\{x\}$. Also, if one replaces " $S$ equal $x$" by "$S$ equal $\{x\}$" in the question, then the answer is yes, but only because of axiom of extensionality.

Comment: More generally there is actually no real reason why $\in$ should mean "in". We think of it like that, but it only behaves like that because of the axioms of ZFC. The first chapter of Halmos' Naive set theory explains that very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If a box contains a pencil, the box is still a box, not a pencil.

In mathematical terms, $S=\{x\}$, but $S\neq x$.

Comment: I think that your example with the pencil and the box is very enlightening.

Comment: Upvoted and accepted because of (idea contained in) @Surb 's comment.

Comment: But if your box *only* has a pencil in it, I'm going to identify the pencil with the box, since finding the box is equivalent to finding a pencil when I'm looking for something to write with.  Also, how do you know what's put in the box is a pencil, and not another box?  Maybe the primitive terms 'set' and 'element' are more closely related than we realize.  (Bear in mind I'm merely playing devil's advocate.)

Answer (score 2):

Just as a further comment on the other (very good) answers, $x=\{x\}$ would contradict the axiom of regularity (if you believe in that sort of thing). So the problem is not "sets vs elements" but rather regularity. In fact in the formalization of ZFC there are no words for sets or elements just an element relation $\varepsilon$, and it is understood that everything is a set, (whose elements if it has any are then in turn other sets.)  Of course as the other answers point out $x$ and $\{x\}$ belong on different levels of the cumulative hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

No. $S$ is the set containing $x$ i.e. $S=\{x\}.$